# GPG: xxxxxxxx: skipped: public key not found

Tags: gnupg

i`ve got a problem with encrypting some stuff on a Debian 8.10 server.

I have a few keys imported into my keyring and am able to check if all that need to be there are actually there with

```
gpg --list-keys
```

Whenever my script runs which contains the following command

```
gpg --trust-model always -r XXXXXXXX -r XXXXXXXX -r XXXXXXXX -r XXXXXXXX -r XXXXXXXX -e
```

i get this error

```
gpg: XXXXXXXX: skipped: public key not found
gpg: [stdin]: encryption failed: public key not found
```

None of the keys that aren't working are expired.

I imported every Key by hand via `gpg --import bla.asc`

If anyone knows what I might be doing wrong - help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If anyone ever approaches the same error - it might be due to the reason I imported the keys on my root account whilst I needed it on a different account. So importing the keys on the right account was my solution.

Comment: *** I was fighting this problem for 4 *** hours, and the root cause was that, I created the keys with not as an administrator -__- A big thank for you!

Answer (score 0):

Hi for me same key is working on lower Environment but not production i got following  error  on prod :: No Public Key
Reason :: on prod Environment Public key is imported for root as well as another user. I removed from Root users and import again with my own user again it start encrypting the file.